# MSP430G2553 with MAX30100 library compiling errors

Tags: embedded, msp430

I am trying to work on MSP430G2553 with MAX30100 pulse oximeter sensor but the energia max30100-master library is not working. These errors are I am trying to fix. How can I get these components to work with energia? I tried different libraries but it always says multiple libraries found. I deleted all and tried again and again but I am still getting same the errors.

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the error messages as separate? I suggest using the  _copy error messages_ option

Comment: Please [edit] your question to paste the error messages as text instead of providing an image.